# Im learning JavaScript can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong? The sum is supposed to give me and 8

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell me what I have wrong?

```js
function main(name, num) {
  console.log("Maria");
  console.log("5 + 3");
}
main();
```

its suppose to give me 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"5+3"` is a string. Remove the quotations if you want to perform an arithmetic operation on the two numbers.

```js
function main(name, num) {
console.log("Maria");
console.log(5 + 3);
}
main()
```